# Sending emails with CodeIgniter getting PHP error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3

im trying to teach myself codeignighter and currently learning sending emails.

I am trying to load the email library and i keep getting "Undefined property: Email::$load" error.

Ive tried for the last hour to find the problem but cant find out whats wrong, any help is much appreciated.

my **email.php**

```
    <?php
class Email extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::get_instance();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => '****s@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => '******'
        );

        $this->load->library('email', $config);

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from('****@gmail.com' , 'joe blog');
        $this->email->to('****@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('this is a test');
        $this->email->message('it is working .... great!');

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            echo 'your email was sent';
        }

        else
        {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Is it coming from this line? `$this->load->library('email', $config);`

Comment: use parent::__construct(); not parent::get_instance();

Comment: @ajmedway yes it is, the error is Message: Undefined property: Email::$load and Message: Call to a member function library() on a non-object

Comment: you are using  $this, not $CI ... use parent::__construct();

Comment: @devpro thank you, i will try this out, looks like that was the problem. just got a error with local host now but im sure i can fix that. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same error.

Try to load email library, and then the email configuration like this:

```
// email
$this->load->library('email');      
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => '********@gmail.com', // your user.
    'smtp_pass' => '****' // your password
);      
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

Here you have the official documentarion about it:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Regards.

also as mentioned from @ devpro

use

```
parent::__construct();
```