# Using codeiniter email library on message send I am seeing error message: Undefined property: CI_Email::$print_debugger

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on the Codeigniter email library on message send its displaying me an error message: Undefined property: CI_Email::$print_debugger. I have also checked this on my online server but not worked for me.

Here is code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'home';
    $this->load->view("template", $data);
}
public function refinanceEmail()
{

    $zip                    = $this->input->post("zip");
    $propertyValue          = $this->input->post("propertyValue");
    $mortgageBalance        = $this->input->post("mortgageBalance");
    $creditscore            = $this->input->post("creditscore");
    $city                   = $this->input->post("city");
    $state                  = $this->input->post("state");
    $firstName              = $this->input->post("firstName");
    $lastName               = $this->input->post("lastName");
    $phone                  = $this->input->post("phone");

    // Message
    $message  = "This message is related to Refinance." . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Zip:: " . $zip . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Property Value:: " . $propertyValue . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Mortgage Balance:: " . $mortgageBalance . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Credit Score:: " . $creditscore . "\r\n";
    $message .= "City:: " . $city . "\r\n";
    $message .= "State:: " . $state . "\r\n";
    $message .= "First Name:: " . $firstName. "\r\n";
    $message .= "Last Name:: " . $lastName . "\r\n";  
    $message .= "Phone:: " . $phone . "\r\n";     


    $config = Array(
        'protocol' => '',
        'smtp_host' => 'mail.********.net',
        'smtp_port' => 25,
        'smtp_user' => '*****@******.net',
        'smtp_pass' => '********',
        'mailtype'  => 'text', 
        'charset'   => 'utf-8'
    );         
    $this->load->library('email', $config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from($phone, $firstName . " " . $lastName);
    $this->email->to("submit@example.net");
    $this->email->subject('My Subject');
    $this->email->message($message);

    if($this->email->send())
    {
        redirect('/welcome/thankyou');
    }
    else
    {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger);
        return false;
    }
}
public function thankyou()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'thankyou';
    $this->load->view("template", $data);
}
}
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311878/code-igniter-load-send-email-in-a-library

Comment: Can you please help check the code and where is the problem? I have already searched about it.

Comment: Try to load email library, and then the email configuration like this:

$this->load->library('email');      
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => '********@gmail.com', // your user.
    'smtp_pass' => '****' // your password
);      
$this->load->library('email', $config);

Comment: I am not using gmail I am using my hostgator webmail service.

Comment: It's not matter. Just replace the value in code. Try to load library first and then config parameters. as i given above.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204029/sending-emails-with-codeigniter-getting-php-error

Comment: Yes I replaced and also load the library first but not worked. I think there is error in code, Because I have done the same work some hours ago that is working fine but its not :( dont know where is the error.

Comment: Can you update your question & post full controller code ?

Comment: Please make sure you have defined construct of your controller as given below.


public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
}

Comment: Yes I have added the construct function. I updated the post.

Comment: You have not loaded $config to email library.

Comment: I am using email.php config file and autoload it.

Comment: $this->email->from must contain email address as first argument and name as second. You are passing phone as first argument in $this->email->from.

Comment: [Solved] Boom its worked I changed the phone number ( $phone ) to an email and now its working. Thank you Jay you helped me :)

Comment: Please vote the comment which helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: There is no option to vote the comment. Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow

Comment: I think you just need to add  round brackets() here

     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        return false;

Answer (score 0):

print_debugger is a function, not a property so

```
show_error($this->email->print_debugger);
```

should be

```
show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
```

From this output you'll hopefully be able to work out why the call to send() returned false

Comment: Hi Dazz Knowles, Thank you for Answer! Its solved actually I was using phone number as a parameter instead of email in  $this->email->from() function. Thank you!